# Ambiguous Reference between 'Resources.Resources' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Resources'

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am migrating an app from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core so this is the first time I am seeing this issue.
[image]

When I try to use Resources.Resources, the first 'Resources' defaults to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Resources'
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on a way to force 'Resources.Resources' or ignore 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Resources'? Changing the Resources class names is not an option as those names have many other dependencies.

Comment: Does `global::Resources.Resources` work?

Comment: No, The name 'global' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
@using ResourcesCore = Resources.Resources;
```

and Replacing all `@Resources` with `@ResourcesCore`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).